# How to prevent Visual Studio Code terminal from not showing the correct prompt after deleting characters?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When connecting through ssh with Visual Studio Code and deleting characters from the terminal prompt input, this one is usually left in a bad state. The prompt may be left with some remaining characters that are not rendered, or characters that are rendered but are not actually in the prompt, making it impossible to determine its current state.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is very simple. Under *File>Preferences>Settings* search for `terminal.integrated.localEchoLatencyThreshold` setting and set it to `-1` (or set `terminal.integrated.localEchoEnabled` to `off`).

This disables the local echo latency (delay in which local edits are echoed on the terminal without waiting for server acknowledgement). By doing so, you ensure that the local terminal prompt always has the same state as the server prompt.

Fix found on https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/133885.